# Transfer texture from one mesh to another with transparency?

Tags: texture-baking

I learned that in order to transfer a texture from one mesh to another you use Cycles Bake in Emit mode and sending texture image to emission in the shader editor of principled bsdf, selecting one object as the 'from' and the next object as the 'to'. However, it does not preserve given texture transparency. It puts black wherever transparency is found.

I made a visual guide on how to do this, posting so it's clear what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Is there a way to bake with transparency?

Comment: How do you use the cloth physics to wrap it around a mesh? Run the simulation and let it fall on the other mesh? Or use a Shrinkwrap modifier additionally?

Comment: Well, there's not enough room on this image to explain every detail, I left things out you could figure out yourself through trial and error. I tried shrinkwrap modifier and it came out too wrinkly and distorted, so basically use cloth physics to get it close, then I went into scultping and used smooth brush to really get it looking nice. So basically... edit it until you like the results using whatever techniques you think of. The cloth mesh doesn't have to be touching the target mesh, just get it close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transparency is a mask, a black & white map (`0=transparent`, `1=opaque`). You can store this data in the Alpha channel of an image (RGBA) or use a separate (b&w) image.

Plug this channel in the `Alpha` slot of the Principled BSDF to have transparency. (In EEVEE you have to set the `Blend Mode` in the material's Settings to Alpha Clip, Alpha Hashed, or Alpha Blend to see the transparency. With brush settings Erase/Add Alpha you can paint transparency in blender.)
[image]

### Baking

With the `Emission` node in the material you can bake the `Emit` color to an b&w image. In Gimp or Photoshop you can add this b&w image as alpha channel/tranparency layer to the diffuse color image and save it as `PNG` file. This file format supports  RGBA/transparency.

Back in Blender, connect the Color slot of the `ImageTexture` node (with the baked image) to the Base Color of the BSDF, and the Alpha to the Alpha. Done :)

[image]

Comment: haven't gotten around to testing so i haven't marked this as the correct answer buut... will do it eventually..................